# How to represent special characters in String literals in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am new to Swift and  I am currently reading the "Swift Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide." I came across a challenge that wants me to create a dictionary that represents a state. My dictionary's keys refer to 3 countries. Each key maps onto an array that holds five of the zip codes within that country. I was allowed to make up the country name and zip codes.
The result should match the following:

```
   Georgia has the following zip codes: [30306, 30307, 30308, 30309, 30310,

                                  30311, 30312, 30313, 30314, 30315,

                                  30301, 30302, 30303, 30304, 30305]
```

I was able to get the result as he requested but I wasn't able to get the same format, in my code the results appears in the same line like this:

```
Georgia has the following zip codes: [30306, 30307, 30308, 30309, 30310,30311, 30312, 30313, 30314, 30315, 30301, 30302, 30303, 30304, 30305]
```

and here is my code:

```
      var georgia = ["c1" : [30306, 30307, 30308, 30309, 30310] , "c2" : [30311, 30312, 30313, 30314, 30315 ] , "c3" : [30301, 30302, 30303, 30304, 30305] ]
      var resultArray : [Int] = []
      for zipCodes in georgia.values
      {
        for zip in zipCodes
        {
          resultArray.append(zip)
        }
      }
      print("Georgia has the following zip codes :" , resultArray)
```

I have been trying to figure out how to match the formatting above as he wants me to, but I wasn't able to get the idea. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated but it is standard practice to start method and variable names with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase. It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for your useful information. @rmaddy

Comment: No offense but this challenge is far away from practical programming relevance.

Comment: Are there specific parameters for the challenge?  Without knowing more about it, I'd probably just build the values into a string and add in `\n` (newline) and `\t` (tab) characters as needed for the formatting.

Comment: He mentioned that I might need to search the documentation for how to represent special characters in String literals (e.g., how do you represent a newline in a String?).  Also to look at the documentation for the print() function to use a new parameter called terminator. And he said that this parameter defaults to printing a new line after each String logged to the console, but I will want to do something else. @JohnMontgomery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
let georgia = ["c1" : [30306, 30307, 30308, 30309, 30310] , "c2" : [30311, 30312, 30313, 30314, 30315 ] , "c3" : [30301, 30302, 30303, 30304, 30305] ]

var resultArray = [String]()
for key in georgia.keys.sorted()
{
    let zipCodes = georgia[key]!
    let zipString = zipCodes.map(String.init).joined(separator: ", ")
    resultArray.append(zipString)
}
print("Georgia has the following zip codes : [" + resultArray.joined(separator: ",\n\n\t\t\t\t\t") + "]")
```

It maps each `Int` array to `String` array and joins the items with the `", "` separator to a string. The resulting array is also joined with a comma and a couple of new line and tab characters. Finally the brackets are added *manually*.

But I can't imagine that this is the actual challenge...

Comment: Thank you very much!!! He mentioned that There are many ways to solve this challenge, but one way would be to print a String with a certain number of empty spaces when I print specific zip code

Comment: He also said that I might need to search the documentation for how to represent special characters in String literals (e.g., how do you represent a newline in a String?). Also to look at the documentation for the print() function to use a new parameter called terminator. And he said that this parameter defaults to printing a new line after each String logged to the console, but I will want to do something else.

Comment: Yes, but there are more practical examples than rebuilding an array as a literal string with an arbitrary format.

Comment: `map({ "\($0)" })` can also be written as `map(String.init)`

Comment: @vadian `let result = georgia.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }).map({ "\($0.value)" }).joined(separator: ", ")`

Comment: @LeoDabus I know, I was almost going to write that. But I don't want to confuse the OP too much.

Comment: Yes, totally understand your point. I am still a beginner, and I was advised to do all the challenges provided by the book so I can understand more. Thanks again for your help. Appreciate it a ton. @vadian